# How to draw two different subplots using matplotlib adjacent to each other?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I have two different plots, first one is `Frequency` vs `Features` and other is `Frequency` vs `Yield` Loss.

Each of the plot is a bar chart with a trendline which shows cumulative% or the Yield Loss on the right side of Y-axis.

So, for each of the graph, the X-axis shows the features name, the left Y-axis shows the frequency, and the right Y-axis shows the Cummulative% or Yield Loss.

Here is the code I have written and it shows the following output.

```
#Trendline_change_2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = df.iloc[:HOW_MANY,:]['FailCount'].plot(kind="bar",stacked = True,legend=False,figsize=(8,8), label = 'frequency plot',color = 'green',title="Frequency of failure vs Feature")  #Graph naming changes
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')
ax1.set_xticklabels(np.asarray(df['Feature'])[:HOW_MANY])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.asarray(df['Cummulative_aggr'])[:HOW_MANY],linestyle='--', marker='s',label ='cummulative %', color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('Cummulative %', color='r')

plt.legend(loc='best')

#Plot 2

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = df.iloc[:HOW_MANY,:]['FailCount'].plot(kind="bar",stacked = True,legend=False,figsize=(8,8), label = 'frequency plot',color = 'green',title="Frequency of failure vs Feature")  #Graph naming changes
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')
ax1.set_xticklabels(np.asarray(df['Feature'])[:HOW_MANY])

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.asarray(df['Yield_Loss'])[:HOW_MANY],linestyle='--', marker='s',label ='Yield Loss', color='black')
ax2.set_ylabel('Yield Loss', color='black')


plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Everything is fine **except I would want to change the two plots side-by-side than one below another**.

I have tried a couple of things to get them side by side like `plt.subplot(1,2,1)` and other parameters but the outcome isn't satisfactory.

Can anyone help me tweak this? I know I am close but not able to get it right.

Comment: Your code would create two figures. Why does your sample output show subplots? Do you work in an environment like Jupyter or similar where the inline plotting makes you think you have two subplots of one figure?

Comment: @Mr.T Hi. Actually I want two figure like the image I have attached. Just want them adjacent than one below other. Also you are correct, I am indeed using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Now it gets confusing. A figure in matplotlib is a different entity from a subplot. You can have multiple subplots in a figure that you can arrange within matplotlib. Or you can have one subplot within each figure - but to arrange these figures, you have to instruct  the program that controls your output, which seems to be in your case Jupyter. These two questions ("How to arrange subplots in matplotlib" and "How to arrange figures in Jupyter") are distinct because the answers will differ. So, which question is it that you have? I added the tag `Jupyter`, in case it is the second question.

Comment: @Mr.T I am sorry if I am making it confusing. Let me put it in simple words, I want the two subplots to be arranged side by side. The cummulative% and Yield Loss one. To get the cumulative % plot, I coded from #Trendline_change_2 till the #plot tag, and for the below plot, the code starts from #plot 2.

In each figure, I have a bar graph, with frequency on left axis, and a line, which shows the trend, and maps with right Y axis. 

This is same for both the plots. 

I hope I am not using terminology incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Jupyter environment with inline image display makes it difficult to understand why figures and subplots are not the same. The matplotlib answer to your question has already been given - [create subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) and fill them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Figure 1, 2 subplots
fig, (ax1, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))

#subplot 1
ax1.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), c="blue")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.arange(5, 15), np.random.randint(10, 100, 10), c="red", label="Subplot 1")
plt.legend(loc="best")

#subplot 2
ax4 = ax3.twinx()
ax3.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(2,20, 10), c="grey")
ax4.plot(np.arange(5, 15), np.random.randint(-10, 0, 10), c="yellow", label="Subplot 2")

#now plot both subplots into one figure
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This creates one figure (think one window or page) with both subplots:

[image]

Your approach is to create two individual figures, each containing one subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Figure 1
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), c="blue")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.arange(5, 15), np.random.randint(10, 100, 10), c="red", label="Figure 1")
plt.legend()


#Figure 2
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.randint(2,20, 10), c="grey")
ax2.plot(np.arange(5, 15), np.random.randint(-10, 0, 10), c="yellow", label="Figure 2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This creates two figures, as expected. In my environment, these are two windows:

[image]

In your environment (guesswork here, because I do not know Jupyter), the inline printing puts the two figures on separate lines - hence, they appear as if you created two vertically arranged subplots in matplotlib.
In summary, this seems to be a Jupyter question - "How do I plot inline images side by side?", not a matplotlib question, if I understand you correctly. Having said that - wouldn't it be easier to answer the question "How can I arrange subplots in matplotlib?" (you got already several answers), and then just plot one figure? It is difficult to see why you need two figures and then display them side by side.

Comment: HI. I think you gave me a correct direction and after some changes I feel I am much closer. Closing this question, marking yours correct(I will need to make customization according to my needs). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)` should works just fine. Then you create your figures using ax1 and ax2 like you did.
[Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

Comment: I am not sure if I exactly got what you are saying. Here is the changes I made [link](https://pastebin.com/PwAzr3dh) and the output [link] (https://imgur.com/a/jTSr6Wa). Can you point out where to make correct changes?

Comment: Ok this is better, however you need only one fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2), since you paste it two times you have 4 plots. Then you use ax1 to create first plot and ax2 for second plot.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
```

```
plt.subplots(a,b)
```

a - No. of plots in each column

b - No. of plots in each row

https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Check the above documentation for a better understanding.

Comment: I am no sure if I exactly got what you are saying. Here is the changes I made [link](https://pastebin.com/PwAzr3dh) and the output [link] (https://imgur.com/a/jTSr6Wa). Can you point out where to make correct changes?

Comment: I have checked your code, I think you have written the same code twice.
Remove the code under """"#Plot 2"""" (which is repetitive) and try again once.